# Apply linear-gradient animation to mesh/grid overlay only

Tags: css, css-animations, linear-gradients

I am breaking my neck over an idea I have and perhaps I am handling it completely wrong and could use some other input/ideas.

The idea is to have an animated gradient being applied to a mesh/grid lines only.

Here is a codepen of what I have now:
https://codepen.io/monsmado/pen/ewRgOR

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#pattern {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0px, transparent 1px), 
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: -2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -8px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #246655, #662464);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pattern"></div>
```

I cannot think of how to apply that animated gradient just to the grid. Perhaps with a css layer mask or something. I found some other solutions that works with some java-script and canvas, but am not that familiar with canvas yet.

Here's an **example image** of what it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXRSp.jpg
The gradient is being applied to the lines/grid only and background could be anything. The linear-gradient should become animated.

Any help or thought of how to approach this would be very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) to do this. You will need to create two layers where the mask will be a `repeating-linear-gradient` that will keep only the lines visible. The first layer for the horizonal ones and the second for the vertical ones:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/800) center/cover;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, purple, green, orange);
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  animation: AnimationName 2s ease infinite alternate;
}
body:before {  
  -webkit-mask-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px);
  mask-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px);
}
body:after {  
  -webkit-mask-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px);
  mask-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px);
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

Or using multipe mask like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/800) center/cover;
}

body:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, purple, green, orange);
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  animation: AnimationName 2s ease infinite alternate;
  -webkit-mask: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,  transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px);
  mask: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,  transparent 0 19px, #fff 19px 20px);
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that really helped me out. 
Is it also possible to apply this to an .png image that has the grid. Because the grid it needs to be like skewed from a certain direction. 
https://codepen.io/monsmado/pen/PrjaeX
In the codepen you can see in the background image what I mean by the grid being skewed or transformed.

Comment: My bad about saying png. It would better to apply it to an svg and updated the pen therefore as well. Svg would be better to preserve quality.

Comment: @Mark well, this is a different thing then. I advice you to ask a seperate question about the SVG so you can get help from SVG people since it's actually out of the scope of this question and I won't be able to help you with it.